# Using have or has and was or were correctly in the given sentences (singular/plural)

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the correct form (singular or plural) of the following two sentences:

> A particular amount of students has/have access.
>
> A particular amount of students was/were selected.

In my opinion, it could be either referred to "amount", which would be singular (has/was) or to "students", which would be plural (have/were).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid "particular" in this sentence; it means single; one unit; one thing.

"Amount" also is vague since it can just be one or multiple.

Better yet:

"A few students have access"

"A few students were selected"

"particular amount" is disastrous in my view. 
I'd avoid this construction altogether.

Comment: What do you think about the following improvements: A specific number of students have access. A specific number of students were selected.